# Associar um arquivo com um aplicativo feito no Lazarus em Linux

Tags: delphi, linux, lazarus

Eu desenvolvi uma aplicação no Lazarus na plataforma linux para impressão de relatório, agora preciso ao clicar no arquivo com uma extensão qualquer, ex `arquivo.gsa` , abrir o meu aplicativo lazarus no linux. No windows, não foi tão complicado eu utilizei este codigo:

```
function RegisterLink(Ext, FType, FriendlyName, Cmd: PChar): Boolean;
//
// Tenta associar um tipo de arquivo a um aplicativo
//
// Ext: Extensão a ser registrada.
// FType: Categoria do arquivo
// FriendlyName: Tipo de arquivo
// Cmd: linha de comando para abrí-lo
// RegisterLink('.Bsd','ArqInutil','Arquivo inútil','C:\Windows\Notepad.exe "%1"')
//
var
Key: HKey;
SZEntry: Array[0..255] of Char;
SZSize: LongInt;
begin
Result := True;
if RegOpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,Ext,Key) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
   SZSize := SizeOf(SZEntry);
   RegQueryValue(Key,'',SZEntry,SZSize);
   StrCat(SZEntry,'\Shell\Open\Command');
   if RegOpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,SZEntry,Key) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
      SZSize := SizeOf(SZEntry);
      RegQueryValue(Key,'',SZEntry,SZSize);
      if (StrIComp(SZEntry,Cmd) = 0) then // and (MessageDlg('A extensão "'+StrPas(Ext)+ '" já está associada para '+copy(StrPas(SZEntry),1,22)+#13+'Você deseja substituir a associação atual por esta?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes,mbNo],0) <> IDYES)  then
         begin
         Result := False;
         Exit;
         end;
      end;
   end;
RegCreateKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,Ext,Key);
RegSetValue(Key,'',REG_SZ,FType,StrLen(FType));
RegCreateKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,FType,Key);
RegSetValue(Key,'',REG_SZ,FriendlyName,StrLen(FriendlyName));
StrCat(StrCopy(SZEntry,FType),'\Shell\Open\Command');
RegCreateKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,SZEntry,Key);
RegSetValue(Key,'',REG_SZ,Cmd,StrLen(Cmd));
end;
```

então eu passo essas informações para a função:

```
 RegisterLink('.gsa','ArqGestor','Archivos del Informe',pchar(application.exename+' "%1"'))
```

Agora o problema é como fazer isso em linux?

Comment: deve ter alguma maneira de associar um arquivo contendo texto para abrir em uma aplicação Lazarus. No nome deste arquivo contem algumas informações da pagina que sera impressa. Mesmo que eu utilize o " abra com ", eu preciso pegar o nome do arquivo na execução para passar os parâmetros para a impressora pelo lazarus.

Comment: Depende ele vai me ajudar a associar meu arquivo .gsa contendo texto e passar para o meu aplicativo desenvolvido em Lazarus?? eu preciso clicar neste arquivo e abrir meu programa ja passando o texto deste arquivo para um TMemo, me explique melhor que esse pkge faz. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Voce teria algum tutorial sobre isso? algum exemplo?, se for possivel . Obrigado

Comment: obrigado, aguardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você pode usar o `xdg-utils` para fazer isso em um ambiente Linux.

Primeiramente, você precisará registrar o ícone para o tipo [**MIME**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_mime.types.htm) através do comando:

```
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 48 myicon-file-type.png x-application-mytype
```

Também é necessário criar um arquivo de configuração([*freedesktop Shared MIME documentation*](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/x-mytype">  
   <comment>Algum comentario</comment>
   <comment xml:lang="en">Some comment</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.gsa"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

Instalar o arquivo de configuração:

```
xdg-mime install mytype-mime.xml
```

Isto torna o seu arquivo reconhecido e associado a um ícone.

Para mais informações veja [**aqui**](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor/) e [**aqui**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31836/1608936).

---

**Atualização**

Verifique se o código abaixo funciona para você.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(0)); // executavel.exe
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Param %d : %s', [I, ParamStr(I)]));

  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetCommandLine);
end;
```

Comment: isso resolveria a invocação do meu aplicativo, agora no lado interno do aplicativo Lazarus como que eu pegaria o nome deste arquivo e o conteúdo? para alimentar um TMemo e mandar imprimir o texto com as informações do titulo?

Ex:

Usuario Click ==> meuarquivo.gsa ==> aplicativo.executavel ==> alimenta Memo ==> Imprime

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @DBX8, ficarei muito grato por esta ajuda.

Comment: Estarei realizando os teste, Obrigado, Logo retorno confirmando se deu tudo certo